# Paypal Sandbox IPN no Response

Tags: php, zend-framework, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am using Zend Framework 2 as my listener for a Paypal payment.
My listener is triggered when the payment is made in the sandbox environment, but when I generate the request to reply to Paypal in order to get a VERIFIED or INVALID response I do not get a response.
There is nothing coming up in the web server logs, no errors and no exception is thrown.
Have tried both the dispatch and Send methods.

Is there any way I can see if the request is sent to Paypal sandbox?
Anywhere in the sandbox I can see this?
Or is there any way I can see the response come back.
Am using Amazon WS but I don't think it's getting blocked as the listener is initially triggered.

Many thanks

Code for IPN listenter is below:

```
$request1 = $this->getRequest();

    // Follow Paypal IPN protocol
    // First send back to PayPal received request
    $request = new Request();
    $request->setMethod(Request::METHOD_POST);

    $client = new Client();
    $client->setRequest($request);
    $client->setUri('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate');

    $postArray = $request1->getPost()->getArrayCopy();
    $client->setParameterPost($postArray);

    $requestHeaders  = $client->getRequest()->getHeaders();

    try {

        $response = $client->send();
        //$response = $client->dispatch($request);

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        $logger->info("Exception:");
        $logger->info($e->getMessage());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the paypal code on https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/IPN_PHP.txt to solve the above.